# Ecto creating unique index failed for Mysql/Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, elixir, ecto

I try to do the following migration:

```
defmodule Shopper.Repo.Migrations.MakeNameUniqueShopper do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create unique_index :shoppers, [:name]
  end
end
```

Also tried `create unique_index :shoppers, [:name], name: :name_unique`, `create unique_index :shoppers, [:name], name: "name_unique"`, and `create index(:shoppers, [:name], unique: true)`

But they failed with similar error:

```
[info]  == Running Shopper.Repo.Migrations.MakeNameUniqueShopper.change/0 forward

[info]  create index shoppers_name_index
** (Mariaex.Error) (1071): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:172: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/5
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1261: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
...
...
```

Any help would be very appreciated, to help me with the error.

**Note**: I'm using ecto 1.02

Following is the first migration created with `mix phoenix.gen.model`

```
defmodule Shopper.Repo.Migrations.CreateV1.Shopper do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:shoppers) do
      add :name, :string
      add :oauth_token, :string

      timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Info**: the `name` field is utf8mb4, specified by my schema

**Update**: I know the solution is to reduce the `name` field length, but how to make it work with phoenix model and migration? As it expects a string?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss the specifics.

Comment: @RickJames I'm not sure it's relevant here. It's created by `mix phoenix.gen.model`

Comment: How can we tell the fields that it's using in the key without seeing the structure of the table?  That's what @RickJames is asking for (if I'm understanding correctly).

Comment: added the creation script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to José Valim for helping me through his answer, though this answer is the exact solution for my problem.

Create a new ecto migration script with the following code:

```
defmodule Shopper.Repo.Migrations.MakeNameUniqueShopper do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:shoppers) do
      modify :name, :string, size: 100
    end

    create unique_index :shoppers, [:name], name: :shopper_name_unique
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The field "name" is too long. You should either ensure it has size less than 767 bytes by passing the size option when declaring it or index just part of the field:

```
create unique_index :shoppers, ["name(20)"], name: :shoppers_name_unique
```

Keep in mind that you will need to give the same name when calling `unique_constraint/2` in your changeset.

Comment: I missed a point about a field should less than 767 bytes, which a string in `add :name, :string` is actually `varchar(255)`. But `["name(20)"]` is not a correct field name, so lead to another error

Comment: I think the correct answer would be migrating it first to `name(20)` then `create unique_index :shoppers, [:name], name: :shopper_name_unique`

Comment: and... my schema is utf8mb4

Comment: but... ecto seems don't have a method to set `name` as `varchar(20)`, since it expects a `string` in elixir?

Comment: Here is the syntax for adding a field with size: `add :name, :string, size: 100`

Comment: If you end up with `UNIQUE name(20)`, it won't be what you want. That constrains _only_ the first 20 characters of `name` to be unique.  These city names would be treated as identical:  `Cortijada El Barranco de Amatisteros`, `Cortijada El Barranco de las Minas`, `Cortijada El Barranco de los Lobos`

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is InnoDB's key size (767 bytes) which directly maps to the possible size of `varchar()` columns with respect to the column's charset. if you use the charset `utf8`, a `varchar` column can store 255 characters at max. if you use `utf8mb4`, a `varchar` column can only store 191 characters.

this blog post goes into full details: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

while applying this rule to the index, like josé suggests, is certainly one possiblity, i'd say you better fix your varchar column sizes and have `CREATE INDEX` not complain in the first place and have a proper table column layout:

```
defmodule Shopper.Repo.Migrations.CreateV1.Shopper do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:shoppers) do
      add :name, :varchar, size: 191
      add :oauth_token, :varchar, size: 191

      timestamps
    end
    create unique_index(:shoppers, [:name])
  end
end
```

> **attention**: `add :name, :string, size: 191` will not work as ecto maps the `:string` type directly to `varchar(255)` [in the mysql adapter](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/c89754c65678cdad598f7b770294912052f5f54a/lib/ecto/adapters/mysql/connection.ex#L672)

my opinion is that ecto's mysql adapter should take the charset into consideration when mapping `:string` to its native type [just like rails does it](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8744632fb5649cf26cdcd1518a3554ece95a401b).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to creating shorter varchar/text column sizes with utf8mb4 encoding is to configure MySQL to increase the maximum InnoDB index prefix size to 3072 bytes.

```
defmodule Shopper.Repo.Migrations.CreateV1.Shopper do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    # just needs to be done once
    execute "SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = BARRACUDA"
    execute "SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = ON"
    execute "SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = ON"

    # in MySQL 5.7.9 or higher, this sets the default row format
    # otherwise for all new tables you create, you must manually 
    # alter row_format to dynamic before adding any string/text columns
    execute "SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format = DYNAMIC"

    # change existing shoppers row format to dynamic
    execute "ALTER TABLE shoppers ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC"

    create unique_index :shoppers, [:name], name: :shopper_name_unique         
  end
end
```