# How to controller-test unique constraints in Elixir / Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Following up on [Making a field unique in ecto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460920/making-a-field-unique-in-ecto) and [Testing Validations in Elixir and Ecto](https://medium.com/@diamondgfx/testing-validations-in-elixir-and-ecto-677bd8a071a1#.5k2i55axe), I am failing to setup a controller test for unique constraints:

```elixir
test "POST /imports will not store duplicate address" do
  # Create the existing (conflicting) record:
  location = "melee island"
  MyApp.Repo.insert! %MyApp.Location{address: location}

  post("/imports", %{"location" => location})

  # Other assertions omitted

  # Check if the location was indeed NOT inserted
  query = from l in MyApp.Location,
    where: [address: ^location],
    select: l.address

  assert MyApp.Repo.all(query) == [location]
end
```

The last assertion fails with the following error:

> (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (in_failed_sql_transaction): current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I understand why – everything is wrapped into a test transaction – but I cannot rollback without losing the initially inserted record. Is there a way to get this behaviour tested?

Comment: Can you also post your controller code? The correct way to use `unique_constraint` is to match on value returned by `Repo.insert` in your controller. This shouldn't throw errors at all.

Comment: The `unique_constraint` works alright and the corresponding unit test works nicely. It's just that I cannot do anything with `Repo` after the DB transaction failed at the attempt to insert a duplicate key.